# How can I enumerate a property in an array of objects, modify it, and join them in a string in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I enumerate a property in an array of objects, modify it, and join them in a string? I know there must be Ruby features that make this easier, but I have been having trouble understanding them.

How can I accomplish this more efficiently (less code/easier to read)?

```
arr = Array.new
someArrayOfObjects.map{
  |obj| arr.push(obj.someProp + '-addThisStr')
}
puts arr.sort.uniq.join(', ')

#end result:
somepropA-addThisStr,somepropB-addThisStr, etc
```

Comment: read up the difference between `map` and `each` methods.

Comment: I'm not sure to what extent uniq is guaranteed to preserve order, or whether there might be changes to that in the future, but if it were me I'd prefer uniq.sort over sort.uniq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have it but you can skip the `Array.new` and `arr.push`:

```
result = someArrayOfObjects.map do |obj|
  obj.someProp + '-addThisStr'
end.sort.uniq.join(", ")

puts result
```